# How to run titan server in embedded tomcat?

Tags: tomcat7, titan, embedded-tomcat-7

I've been looking around for a way to run a titan server in tomcat, but I can't find any information about this.

Anyone that knows how this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are asking about running "Titan Server" in Tomcat, that really just means how to run [Rexster](http://rexster.tinkerpop.com) inside of Tomcat.   We dropped official support for Tomcat many, many versions ago, but I believe there are still those have it deployed that way which means it is in fact possible.  I guess this would also only apply to hosting the Jersey-based REST endpoints and not RexPro.

To get started I would simplify the stack and just get Rexster running in Tomcat.  I would search around the [gremlin-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gremlin-users) for what people have posted on the topic, but I think that this one is the most relevant:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gremlin-users/s0g9Sd_xjSw/LQ3_ugL680cJ

If I remember correctly the key to making things work lies in this Rexster class: [RexsterApplicationProvider](https://github.com/tinkerpop/rexster/blob/2.5.0/rexster-server/src/main/java/com/tinkerpop/rexster/server/RexsterApplicationProvider.java).  Note the class comments with the sample `web.xml` fragment.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! So this means that it is not possible to run Titan alone (without using rexster) ?

Comment: The reason why I want to do this is because I have windows OS and I wnat to start the Titan server through Tomcat. I do not want to use cygwin.

Comment: "Titan Server" is a packaging of Titan and Rexster together so using "Titan Server" implies use of Rexster.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you just to fire up an instance of Titan with Cassandra etc when Tomcat starts?

If this is the case you can make a InitialListener in your web.xml that starts a Singleton or service that starts up the titan graph connection and then you can use it in your other servlets/whatever code base you have running.